# Eigenvalue find the matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be the matrix with eigenvalues $1,2$ and $3$. Find matrix with dimension $4$x$4$ that satisfies this.

Comment: What if you wrote a diagonal matrix with one of those eigenvalues repeated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example: $$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Then 3 is two times the eigenvalue. Like others also said it.

Comment: -1 for no explanation. Also, "3 is two times the eigenvalue" is confusing. Better written as:
"3 is a repeated eigenvalue"
or
"3 is an eigenvalue with multiplicity 2"

Comment: Yes, thats true. Mulitplicity is a better word.

Answer (score 2):

There are many solutions to this problem.

If $D$ is the diagonal matrix $D=\operatorname{diag}(a,b,c,d)=\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & b & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & c & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & d \end{pmatrix}$

Since $1,2,3$ are eigenvalues of $A$ then there exists an invertible matrix $P$
such that $A=PDP^{-1}$ with $D$ such that $a=1,b=2,c=3$ and $d=1\text{ or }2\text{ or }3$.

Note that the order does not matter, if $D_1=\operatorname{diag}(1,2,3,1)$ and $D_2=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,2,3)$ for instance, there is always a change of base such that $D_1$ and $D_2$ represent the same application.

So if $A=PD_1P^{-1}$ and $D_1=QD_2Q^{-1}$ then $A=(PQ)D_2(PQ)^{-1}$.

In the end, that's a lot of possibilities for $A$, three choices for $D$ but an infinity for $P$.

But this is not the end, because for instance the triangular matrix $T=\begin{pmatrix} a & * & * & * \\ 0 & b & * & * \\ 0 & 0 & c & * \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & d \end{pmatrix}$

where the $*$ represent random numbers, also has $a,b,c,d$ as eigenvalues.

Thus all $A=PTP^{-1}$ would be solution too.

Same for inferior triangular matrices too.

Comment: Same as what I was typing!

Answer (score 2):

Think about the definition of the eigenvalue:
$$\det(A-\lambda I)=0$$
What is the simplest matrix you could construct with a non-zero determinant?

Answer: diagonal matrix - determinant is product of diagonal entries.
$$\det \left(\matrix{a_1&0&\dots&0\\
                     0&a_2&\dots&0\\
                     \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
                     0&0&\dots&a_n}\right)=a_1 \times a_2 \times \dots \times a_n$$
So the eigenvalue equation can be written:
$$(a_1-\lambda_1)(a_2-\lambda_2)\dots(a_n-\lambda_n)=0$$
Since you know three eigenvalues, but need a matrix of size-$4$, I would repeat one of the eigenvalues. (For convenience, I repeated the first).
$$(a_1-1)(a_2-1 \text{  repeated!})(a_3-2)(a_4-3)=0$$
Then, to find the entries in the matrix, find the zeros of the equation:
$$\matrix{a_1 = 1\\a_2=1\\a_3=2\\a_4=3}$$
Therefore, one of the possible matrices that satisfies the given conditions would be:
$$\left(\matrix{1&0&0&0\\
                     0&1&0&0\\
                     0&0&2&0\\
                     0&0&0&3}\right)$$